# Resize jpopupmenu using Mouse Adapter

Tags: java, swing, listener, mouse, mousemotionlistener

I'm using the [Swing bits](https://github.com/eugener/oxbow) library to add filters to my jtable column headers. The library works as expected, but the jpopupmenu that appears on a column right click does not re-size. (re-sizing allowed only from the bottom right corner using a mouse drag) Screenshot shown below.

[image: Swing Bits column filter jpopupmenu]

I got hold of the swing bits library source code to try and figure out this issue, This is what I found.

The jpopupmenu resizing is handled by a MouseMotionListner and a MouseListener. Basically a MouseDragged method gets called continuously, which should update the jpopupmenu size until the mouse is released. The code is shown below.

```
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    //System.out.println("test_0"); 

    if ( !isResizing ){
    //System.out.println("test_3"); 
    return;}

    Point p = toScreen(e);

    int dx = p.x - mouseStart.x;
    int dy = p.y - mouseStart.y;

    Dimension minDim = menu.getMinimumSize();
    Dimension newDim = new Dimension(startSize.width + dx, startSize.height + dy);

    if ( newDim.width >= minDim.width && newDim.height >= minDim.height) {
        menu.setPopupSize(newDim);
        //System.out.println("test_1");         
    }
    //System.out.println("test_2");
}
```

Through a bit of debugging, I realized the problem lies in the menu.setPopUpSize(newDim) method call.

Without this bit of code, the mouseDragged() method gets called continuously when I try to re-size the jpopupmenu.  (as it should) Figured this out using the commented print statements.

With menu.setPopUpSize(newDim) included, the mouseDragged() method is only called once. For some reason, the mouse drag event is not registered again after the call to the setPopUpSize method. Note that the method does NOT return. On that single call, the setPopUpSize() slightly re-sizes the popupmenu with the updated newDim value.
Ideally the mouseDragged() method should be called repeatedly until the user releases the mouse drag action, re-sizing the popupmenu continuously.

One work around I figured is to declare the newDim value publicly and call the setPopUpSize(newDim) method inside the mouseReleased() method. This gets the final coordinates from the mouse drag and uses that to re-size the popup menu. But this does not show the dragging of the edges for the user, which is very inconvenient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Execution without the setPopUpSize(newDim) method:

```
test_0
test_1
test_2
test_0
test_1
test_2 ...
```

this pattern is repeated till the mouse drag is released.

Execution with the setPopUpSize(newDim) method:

```
test_0
test_1
test_2
```

The mouseDragged() method is called only once.

Comment: `setPopupSize`, which is a method of `JPopupMenu` sets the `preferredSize` of the component, if the size changes, it proceeds to hide and reshow the popup

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'it proceeds to hide and reshow the popup' ?

Comment: A call to `setPopupSize`, calls `showPopup`, this will close the current popup (if one is visible) and recreates the window based the new `preferredSize` of the popup.  How the window is actually created is dependent on a number of system critieria.  This could mean that in doing so, the `MouseListener`s which were previously registered "may" become deregistered, at a guess

Comment: And this recreated popupmenu would not respond to the `mouseDragged` listener of the previous menu. As a result the `mouseDragged` method is only called once on each click and drag? Is that it?

Comment: Okay, so the `MouseListener`s remain intact, but, because the window is made visible, the mouse events are no longer been sent to it, but to the window beneath it, and, well, the whole thing explodes in flames. This is a bug that the author of SwingBits is going to have to addresss

Comment: The reference to the `javax.swing.Popup` is a private field in `JPopupMenu` with no means to access it without using reflection, even then, it's heavily protected (most of the methods been package private)

Comment: But if the events are still being sent to the window beneath it, that would mean the `mouseDragged` method is being called continuously, which should show the print out statements on the console?

Comment: They are been sent to the JTable, not the popup component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! Turns out the problem was with the java version. I was running java 1.8.0_25 (x64) , updated it to the latest (1.8.0_66) and the issue has disappeared. The library works fine. More information about this issue can be found here.

https://github.com/eugener/oxbow/issues/44

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour can occur depending on which layout the JPopupMenu is using, there is a way to set the size of the parent window and validating it so the layout is re-calculated again like so:

```
public class ResizePopup {

    private final static JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final JButton small = new JButton("Small");
        small.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                resize(100, 100);
            }
        });

        final JButton big = new JButton("Big");
        big.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                resize(400, 400);
            }
        });

        menu.add(small);
        menu.add(big);
        menu.show(null, 50, 50);
    }

    private static void resize(final int width, final int height) {
        final Window window = (Window) menu.getTopLevelAncestor();
        window.pack();
        window.setSize(width, height);
        window.validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have checked those values, the new dimensions fall within the limits. 
Added menu.repaint() does not work. The problem is there is only a single call to the mouseDragged() method which re-sizes the popupmenu by a fraction.Ideally the menu should keep re sizing with the mouse drag like a normal re sizable window.

Comment: This does not work. I came across a similar answer [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1353549?start=0&tstart=0). The top level window returned by `menu.getTopLevelAncestor` is the window of the jtable, and resizing the popupmenu changes the size of the entire table.

Comment: Can't you set the maximum column width then?